# ORACLE Update with MINUS result

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle 10g, I want to update the records of the resulting minus query below:

```
(
 SELECT A,B,C FROM Table1

  MINUS

 SELECT A,B,C FROM Table2
)
```

The column that is to be updated is not part of the minus query as its not present in both tables so the below code is not an option

```
UPDATE
(
 SELECT A,B,C FROM Table1

  MINUS

 SELECT A,B,C FROM Table2
)
SET TABLE1.D = 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
update table1
   set d = 'TEST'
 where (a,b,c) not in(select a,b,c from table2);
```

**Edit**:
The performance of minus generally suck, due to the sort operation. 
If any of `{a,b,c}` are nullable, try the following instead:

```
update table1 t1
   set t1.d = 'TEST'
 where not exists(
         select 'x'
           from table2 t2
          where t2.a = t1.a
            and t2.b = t1.b
            and t2.c = t1.c
       );
```

Comment: This works. It's however hugely lacking performance in comparison with how fast the MINUS gets the differences.

Comment: Both solutions work. I'm looking thou for an implementation using MINUS. I've tested it to be faster than the WHERE (a,b,c) not in (select a,b,c) and easier to implement than the not exists solution for tables with lots of columns.

Comment: So far I'm going with the NOT IN solution you posted.

Comment: what's the difference in the explain-plan? our experience was that the not-exists anti-right-join is often faster than some kind of not-in nested loop ... of course that depends on your data ...

Comment: @Joel, In Oracle there is a difference in execution strategy between NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS when the columns are nullable. I really recommend you try the NOT EXISTS version as well. Anyway, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment about wanting to use the `minus` clause:

```
update Table1
  set d = 'TEST'
  where (a,b,c) in (select a,b,c from Table1 minus select a,b,c from Table2);
```